# Form submit button not submitting any data on MS Edge

Tags: forms, button, submit, microsoft-edge

I have two buttons in the form-foot. the first one should load a different page with how-to-use tips, the second triggers a popup. The first has only attributes, the second one has binded jquery event on click which works. However on MS Edge the first button loads the page which is loaded also after the popup interaction triggered by the second btn.. That happens only on Edge. It works on IE 11, Chrome & Firefox. Is there any solution? Am I missing something?

```
<form method="POST" id="start-exam-form" novalidate="novalidate">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="nFgf0NGZKushRlwFnTc3AAsB7JFMTAG5">
                    <div class="form-body">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-label">First name *</label>
                            <div class="form-controls">

                                     <input class="field" data-msg-required="*This field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="id_first_name" maxlength="50" name="first_name" placeholder="" type="text" value="martin" aria-required="true">

                             </div><!-- /.form-controls -->

                        </div><!-- /.form-row -->
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <label class="form-label">Last name *</label>
                            <div class="form-controls">

                                     <input class="field" data-msg-required="*This field is required." data-rule-required="true" id="id_last_name" maxlength="50" name="last_name" placeholder="" type="text" value="todorov" aria-required="true">

                            </div><!-- /.form-controls -->

                        </div><!-- /.form-row -->

                         <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-controls">
                                <div class="checkbox-wrapper">

                                        <input data-msg-required="*Please confirm your identity." data-rule-required="true" id="id_confirm_identity" name="confirm_identity" type="checkbox" checked="checked" aria-required="true">

                                    <label for="id_confirm_identity">
                                        <span class="checkbox"></span>
                                        <span>I confirm my identity</span>
                                    </label>

                                </div> <!-- /.checkbox-wrapper -->
                            </div> <!-- /.form-controls -->
                        </div> <!-- /.form-row -->

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-controls">
                                <div class="checkbox-wrapper">

                                        <input data-msg-required="*Please accept our policy." data-rule-required="true" id="id_is_accepted_terms" name="is_accepted_terms" type="checkbox" checked="checked" aria-required="true">

                                    <label for="id_is_accepted_terms">
                                        <span class="checkbox"></span>
                                        <span>I agree to the <a href="/terms-and-conditions">T&amp;C</a> and <a href="/privacy-policy">Privacy Policy</a></span>
                                    </label>

                                </div> <!-- /.checkbox-wrapper -->
                            </div> <!-- /.form-controls -->
                        </div> <!-- /.form-row -->

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-controls">
                                <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
                                    <input id="id_receive_future_job_offers" name="receive_future_job_offers" type="checkbox">
                                    <label for="id_receive_future_job_offers">
                                        <span class="checkbox"></span>
                                        <span>I want to receive future job offers</span>
                                    </label>

                                </div> <!-- /.checkbox-wrapper -->
                            </div> <!-- /.form-controls -->
                        </div> <!-- /.form-row -->
                    </div><!-- /.form-body -->
                    <div class="form-foot">
                        <button name="start_exam_guide_btn" type="submit" form="start-exam-form" class="btn btn-white start-exam-guide-btn" value="start-guide"><span>Exam guide</span></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-green-light start-exam-button"><span>Start Exam</span></button>
                    </div><!-- /.form-foot -->
                </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `type="submit"` is on the button that loads the guide.
So clicking the other button will not do anything.

If you are using bootstrap, and you appear to be, I would just leave the guide button as a link with the button class
`<a class="btn btn-white start-exam-guide-btn" href="<your link"><span>Exam guide</span></a>`

And move the `type="submit"` to the other button